# URL not found in django

Tags: django-urls

i am a newbie in django
i am  getting an error saying
Using the URLconf defined in portal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^event/ ^$ [name='index']
^event/ ^pg1$ [name='pg1']
^admin/
The current URL, event/event/pg1.html, didn't match any of these.

my views.py file is

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,render
from event.models import Login,Page1

def index(request):
    return render_to_response("event/index.html")

def pg1(request):
    return render_to_response("event/pg1.html")
```

my pg1.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
        {%csrf_token%}
            Branch
            </br>
                <select name="Branch">
                    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                    <option value="CSD">CSD</option>
                    <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                </select>
            </br>
        </br>
        Event Name: <input type="text" name="eventname"><br>
        </br>
        Test Date :<input type="date" name="test_date"><br>
        Test Time:<input type="time" name="test_time"><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

my index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="input" action="/event/pg1.html" method="post">
{%csrf_token%}
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit" Value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my urls.py file:

```py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include 
from event import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^pg1$', views.pg1, name='pg1'),
)
```

Comment: Use different code blocks for different files. You tried to separate them with the containing file name, but it is ruining the syntax highlighting ;].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bypassing the Django URL thing while doing `action="/event/pg1.html"`. Here is [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/) related to forms when using Django.

When you need to specify a handler view in the `action` attribute of a form (aka when the view which generated the form and the view which should handle its POST datas are not the same), feed it the associated URL.

If I correctly understood what you are trying to do, you should have `action="/event/pg1/"` in your form.

Comment: i m sorry for bad syntax as i m not familiar with stackoverflow syntax :(

Comment: I tried action="/event/pg1/" that also doesn't work. and when i m trying to directly go to 127.0.0.1:8000/event/index the error is same  Using the URLconf defined in portal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:<br/> ^event/ ^$ [name='index']<br/> ^event/ ^pg1/$ [name='pg1']<br/> The current URL, event/pg1, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @GargSanket, The only thing I can see right now is that your URL `event/pg1` doesn't match `event/pg1/`. But the trailing slash shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @GargSanket, It appears that Django can automatically add a trailing slash when needed, but doesn't remove any if not. Glad I could help, feel free to mark as answered ;].